# Random access string array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I want to compare (`.equals`) strings with user input, like a quiz. Now i have multiple questions:

**1** How can i access my string array `answerlist` at random?(like different (order) questions every time) I tried it with `.random` like this:

```
public String[] questionList = {"question1", "question2", "question3"};
// answer1 is the correct answer to question1 etc. 
public String[] answerList = {"answer1", "answer2", "answer3};
random = new Random();            
answer = answerList[random.nextInt(answerList.length)];
```

**2**
I thought I saw that you can use an (array)list instead of the String array I'm using now. If this is true could you please include an explenation of how to do this. And how to access at random.

**3**And how do I match the random accessed answer with the question displayed for the user? I read something about using classes for this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I just thought of creating an array for every question and answer and then accessing them in one or other way?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "how can I access my string array at random"? Please provide some context on what you're trying to achieve. For instance, is "answer1" the answer to "question1"? If so, you can consider a map data structure.

Comment: @Vinnie I mean that I want a different (order of) questions. Every time. The code runs.

Comment: How has this to do with Android? Sounds like a general java problem to me. In that case, I suggest to remove the [android] tag and add a [java] one.

Comment: What does point `3` even mean?

Comment: I mean that I want to compare the answer with the corresponding question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i access my string array answerlist at random?(like different (order) questions every time).

As you want to change the questions like quiz/randomly, It is suggested that you should map your question and answer together. Shuffling Question list and Answer list is not preferred and doesn't have a solution.

> I thought I saw that you can use an (array)list instead of the String array I'm using now. If this is true could you please include an explenation of how to do this. And how to access at random.
>
> And how do I match the random accessed answer with the question displayed for the user? I read something about using classes for this?

Use below example of `Hashmap` in Java.

```
public class QuestionAnswers {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, String> questionSets = new HashMap<String, String>();
    questionSets.put("Question1", "Answer1");
    questionSets.put("Question2", "Answer2");
    questionSets.put("Question3", "Answer3");
    questionSets.put("Question4", "Answer4");
    questionSets.put("Question5", "Answer5");

    List<Map.Entry<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, String>>(questionSets.entrySet());

    System.out.println("************ Questions ************");
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : list) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        // Here entry.getKey() is Question and if user enters the correct answer 
        // match that answer with like -> "user_answer".equals(entry.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could approach the instantiation of your questions and answers list.

**1. Using a class to hold a question and its associated answer**

You could consider a list of objects, with each object holding the question and its associated answer.

```
class QuestionAnswerPair
{
    final String question;
    final String answer;

    public QuestionAnswerPair(@NonNull String question, @NonNull String answer)
    {
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
}
```

Then to add your questions/answers to a list, you'd do something like this:

```
final List<QuestionAnswerPair> questionsAndAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
QuestionAnswerPair one = new QuestionAnswerPair("my question", "my answer");
questionsAndAnswers.add(one);
// keep creating and adding new questions and answers as needed
```

**2. Using android.util.Pair**

Another option is the [Pair utility class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Pair) in Android:

```
final List<Pair<String, String>> questionsAndAnswers = new ArrayList<>();
questionsAndAnswers.add(Pair.create("question1", "answer1"));
//continue adding as needed
```

From this point, to shuffle your list, you can look up example shuffling algorithms in Google by searching "shuffle list in java" or something along those lines. One such example can be found here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsShuffle/article.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you know how i can access the lists? Like with an array[1].

Comment: You'd do `questionsAndAnswersList.get(index);` to access an element at a specific index. Here's some documentation on the List interface: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment!